# Quicksort median 3 running time

Tags: sorting, case, average

I am considering a quicksort algorithm，The pivot in the partition function is chosen as the median of three (uniformly) randomly chosen items in the array. Does anyone know the running time of the average case?

Comment: This algorithm is called quicksort with pivot element: Try to search for that

Answer (score 0):

Small assumption: all the elements are different.

With this assumption, even if you choose pivot as just a random element, the average running time is O(n * log n).
The most optimistic scenario is also O(n * log n). 
Choosing a median of three random elements doesn't make the average case any worse, so it must also be O(n * log n). 
What you gain by looking at the median is a smaller deviation from the average. 
Such a version of quick-sort is more bad-luck redundant.

If the elements don't have to be different, please consider a case, where they are all equal. 
If your algorithm works still in O(n * log n) time, it will probably be all the same.